# How to install exe file in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have desktop application and i need install exe file in Azure Pipeline. How i can install exe file in my azure pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you have a couple options: either install the software each time you run your pipeline (in a step), or build a custom agent with the software pre-installed. If your application is small and can be installed silently using the command line, installing it on the hosted agent each time is probably fine.

If your application is large, requires a GUI, or can't be silently installed, building a custom agent is likely the best option. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Comment: i can installed silently using the command line, but my pipeline every time generate new version to my exe file,  what command do i need to write to the script so that i dont write the version every time ?